# Mask browser navigator?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

You are probably well aware (probably more than me anyway) that many websites use scripts to fingerprint user's browser by gathering info like resolution and screen-size, OS details, browser version and build, installed add-ons, etc.

Is it possible, using javascript to spoof some/every property of your browser (Chomium/Cef or any other), so that it is impossible for later-loaded scripts to fingerprint your browser or detect the navigator object has been tempered with?

If it's not possible to accomplish using JS then how about extensions and addons?

This might be something obvious for the seasoned web developers of you, but I don't have extensive experience with web development, and can't find a definitive answer online either.

Comment: This isn't really a web development question as you're only asking about your own browser. As such, this is a better fit for https://superuser.com/. Out of curiosity, have you tried searching in your browser's _"add-ons"_ site?

Comment: The browser/OS information is sent via the header information that is sent when requesting information from a server. This can easily be spoofed - google it. The number of plugin, screen res etc can be sent using JavaScript from the browser. To prevent this information being sent then disable JavaScript for the site. There are numerous addons which allow this.

Comment: I view it as a web development because it involves browsers and javascript, I never thought of "is it web development" based on if you do it yourself or do it to others. Anyway, I haven't tagged the question web-development or something like that, so who cares

Comment: @jeff my issue is mainly with the other info and not the requests, or cookies for that matter. But I need to use javascript because many websites does not function without it. My point is, I know I can disable JS but I need to spoof the fingerprint instead